# fit surface to data, matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry-surface

I have data- 3 column. First and second- X and Y coordinates, the third value. I have to fit the surface using square interpolation method. And then plot fit output with a .jpg background.

I have already

`[XOut, YOut, ZOut] = prepareSurfaceData(x, y, v);
 [c,goft]=fit([XOut,YOut],ZOut,'poly02');
plot(c);`

But I dont know` how to change view into XY. And then add background from .jpg file

Please give me some advices.

Comment: the best advice you will ever get whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: I have already

`[XOut, YOut, ZOut] = prepareSurfaceData(x, y, v);

[c,goft]=fit([XOut,YOut],ZOut,'poly02');

plot(c)`

But I dont know` how to change view into XY. And then add background from .jpg file

Comment: So that's the sort of thing that should be in the question if you want help. Show that code and what sort of thing it outputs, etc.

Comment: the post have been changed. I hope SB will help me.

Answer (score 0):

So, as far as I understand this question has nothing to do with fitting, but is about how to put an image on a surface?

You say 'background', but I am not sure if you mean the axis or the surface, but this should work either way (except you need an extra surface with z=0 for the former):

```
% make dummy test data
N = 60;
X = 1:N;
Y = 1:N;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(X,Y);
Z = X - X.^2 + Y.^2 + randn(N,N)*10;

% read jpg and make same size as grid    
im = imread('yourimage.jpg');
% convert image to indexed colours    
[im, map] = rgb2ind(im, 256);

% make figure
figure(1), clf

% make image same size as grid
subimage = im(1:N,1:N);
colormap(map)

% plot surf and use image as texture
s = surf(X,Y,Z);
set(s, 'faceColor', 'texture',...
    'edgecolor', 'none',...
    'cdata', subimage)
```

Is that what you meant?